# Using a validation on a reactive form control that is a component

Tags: angular

How can I run custom validation on this component in the FormBuilder?

For example, when a user selects an item from the dropdown `onClickItem(item)`
how could run a validation function on the selected `item` from the main form component?

**FormBuilder in main form component:**

```
this.itemForm = this.fb.group({
   name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
   description: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]],
   itemName: [] // run validation on this component
});
```

Then I could use a validator on itemName like this: `itemName: [, MyValidator.itemNotUsed],`

**Template:**

```
<app-dropdown-select formControlName="itemName"
     [dropdownItems]="items">
</app-dropdown-select>
```

**Dropdown-Select Component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropdown-select',
  templateUrl: './dropdown-select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dropdown-select.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => DropdownSelectComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class DropdownSelectComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input() combinedInput: boolean;
  @Input() dropdownItems: DropdownItem[];
  _selectedItem: DropdownItem;
  showList: boolean;
  buttonIcon: string;

  propagateChange = (_: any) => {};

  set selectedItem(value) {
    this._selectedItem = value;
    this.propagateChange(this._selectedItem);
  }

  get selectedItem() {
    return this._selectedItem;
  }

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  OnInit() {
    this.buttonIcon = BUTTON_ICON_INACTIVE;
    this.selectedItem = this.dropdownItems[0];
    console.log(this.dropdownItems);
  }

  onClick() {
    this.toggleShowList();
  }

  toggleShowList() {
    this.showList = !this.showList;
    if (!this.showList) {
      this.buttonIcon = BUTTON_ICON_INACTIVE;
    } else {
      this.buttonIcon = BUTTON_ICON_ACTIVE;
    }
  }

  onClickItem(item) {
    this.showList = false;
    this.selectedItem = item;
    this.propagateChange(this.selectedItem);
  }

  writeValue(value: any) {
    if (value !== undefined) {
      this.selectedItem = value;
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    console.log('register change');
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched() {}

}
```

Comment: Start here: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators

Comment: You could pass your FormControl to the component and that would make your life easier. (to pass FormControl you would need an Input() and make something like `[control]="formGroup.get('input')"`

Comment: I'd rather define the validator outside the component then apply it to the control in formbuilder, it think it'd be more maintainable like this

Answer (score 0):

You need add as provider NG_VALIDATORS, see https://medium.com/@tarik.nzl/angular-2-custom-form-control-with-validation-json-input-2b4cf9bc2d73

So, your providers becomes like

```
providers: [
{
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => DropdownSelectComponent),
  multi: true,
},
{
  provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => DropdownSelectComponent),
  multi: true,
}
```

If you need addicional validator in the own component (else you needn't), you can implement Validator and create a function Validate like

```
public validate(c: FormControl) {
    //implement your logic here
    let error:boolean
    return error?{
        customError:"ERROR"
    }:null;
}
```

Comment: That gets a validator working in the dropdown component, now what if want to run it in the form component: itemName: [, MyValidator.itemNotUsed] to make it cleaner

Comment: @coder, If you want to make a validator NOT in the component you should be able to do it without problems. I put an example with two sillys custom component. One with a validate function and the other one with no validate function. see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fj3u12?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdropdown-select.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

define

```
@Output('itemSelected') itemSelected = new EventEmitter(); //in DropdownSelectComponent
```

then when you you select item call

```
this.itemSelected.emit(item);
```

you can get the selected item in main component like this

```
<app-dropdown-select formControlName="itemName"
     [dropdownItems]="items" (itemSelected)="doValidation($event)">
</app-dropdown-select>
```

Comment: Coder was looking for a "validator", when you make a custom form control, you are trying to make a control like a input, or select. You needn't use (itemSelected) -Angular takes care about it for you-