# Reactive Form Validation with custom formcontrol and value accessor

Tags: angular

I am trying to use validation defined in the recative form in the custom formcontrol, actually nothing seems to work, i am even wondering if it is possible.

This is my form

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
    autoComplete: [
        { value: null, disabled: false },
        [Validators.required],
    ],
});
```

and my component

```
<input
#autoCompleteInput
#autoCompleteInputTrigger
type="text"
class="form-control custom-select"
placeholder="{{ placeholder }}"
matInput
[formControl]="input"
[matAutocomplete]="auto"
(click)="onClick($event)"
(focusout)="resetNbClick($event)">
```

Actually my component, using NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, never know when he is invalid, I mean never ng-invalid class is added on it.

Is there a way to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Try by adding `[formControlName]="autoComplete"` in input.

Comment: You don't reference the form group in the template. And we have no idea of what you're talking about with "your component using NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR", since you didn't post any such component. You probably don't need it anyway. I suggest you restart from scratch, following the angular.io documentation carefully, with the most simple (but correct) form (a form with just a basic text input) you can imagine.

Comment: Let me explain better...

I have a component, the one with input, he is using NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR. Let's call it inputComponent.

I have other component that use inputComponent in reactiveForm declaration. All works fine, I can get the value from inputComponent to the one with the reactive form.

But I would like to be able to use validators as well in reactive to mark inputComponent as invalid. However even when FormControl is invalid, inputComponent input does not get ng-invalid class

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53793764/using-a-validation-on-a-reactive-form-control-that-is-a-component