# How to pass NgControl status to child component in Angular, implementing ControlValueAccessor?

Tags: angular

Provided

```
{
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => TestingComponent),
  multi: true
}
```

Injected NgControl

```
constructor(@Self() @Optional() public control: NgControl) {
  this.control && (this.control.valueAccessor = this);
}
```

And yet something is missing here?

[image]

Although @Eliseo answer is very explanatory there is still one addition... If you want to use both external validators and internal ones then parent NgControl Validators must be set accordingly. Furthermore you need to use ngDoCheck lifecycle hook to handle NgControl touch status if you want to use validation as me below is a **final working solution**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-testing',
    templateUrl: 'testing.component.html'
})
export class TestingComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, DoCheck, AfterViewInit {
    @Input()
    public required: boolean;

    @ViewChild('input', { read: NgControl })
    private inputNgModel: NgModel;

    public value: number;
    public ngControlTouched: boolean;

    constructor(@Optional() @Self() public ngControl: NgControl) {
        if (this.ngControl != null) this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
    }

    ngDoCheck() {
        if (this.ngControlTouched !== this.ngControl.touched) {
            this.ngControlTouched = this.ngControl.touched;
        }
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        // Setting ngModel validators to parent NgControl
        this.ngControl.control.setValidators(this.inputNgModel.validator);
    }

    /**
     * ControlValueAccessor Implementation
     * Methods below
     */
    writeValue(value: number): void {
        this.value = value;
        this.onChange(this.value);
    }

    onChange: (_: any) => void = (_: any) => {};

    onTouched: () => void = () => {};

    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.onChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.onTouched = fn;
    }
}

// Template
<input
    #input="ngModel"
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    [class.is-invalid]="input.invalid && (input.dirty || input.touched || ngControlTouched)"
    [(ngModel)]="value"
    (ngModelChange)="onChange(value)"
    (blur)="onTouched()"
    [required]="required"
/>

// Usage
<app-testing [(ngModel)]="propertyDetails.whatThreeWords" name="testing" required></app-testing>
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Child component must be validated (form.controls[key].markAsTouched();) via the parent component NgForm. But the validation is set on a child one. Inecting NgControl doesn't allow me to apply following to child's input [class.is-invalid]="control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched)"

Comment: Can you share code of custom control class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You has two options:

Inject NgControl, for this you need remove the provider and make the constructor in the way

```
constructor(public control:NgControl){
    if (this.control != null) {
      this.control.valueAccessor = this;
    }
  }
```

Then you can decorate your input like

```
<input [ngClass]="{'ng-invalid':control.invalid,'ng-valid':control.valid...}">
```

Or copy the class of the customFormControl to the input.

Your input is like

```
<input [ngClass]="class">
```

If in the constructor of your custom form control import the ElementRef

```
constructor(private el:ElementRef){}
```

And create a function "copyClass"

```
  copyClass()
  {
    setTimeout(()=>{
       this.class=this.elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('class')
    })
  }
```

You can call this function in writeValue,Change and OnTouched.

The most simple example I can imagine is in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9hpb4w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom.component.ts)

NOTE: If your problem is that you're using material angular in your component, the tecnique is using a customErrorMatcher, take a look to the [official docs](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#changing-when-error-messages-are-shown) and, if you want to this answer in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56876119/both-mat-error-show-when-only-one-condition-is-true)

**UPDATE** Another aproach is set the same validators to the input. For this, we use viewChild to get the input and, in ngAfterViewInit equals the validators

```
 @ViewChild('input',{static:false,read:NgControl}) input

 ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    if (this.control != null) {
       this.input.control.setValidators(this.control.control.validator)
    }

  }
```

see [another stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oobutv?file=src/app/custom.component.ts)

**at last update** if we want to has a custom error inside the control, we can use the function validate to get the control and not inject in constructor. The component becomes like

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomFormControlComponent),
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomFormControlComponent),
      multi: true,
    }]

})
export class CustomFormControlComponent implements ControlValueAccessor,
      Validator, AfterViewInit {
  ...
  control:any
  @ViewChild('input', { static: false, read: NgControl }) input
  constructor() {
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.validate(null)
  }
  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null{
    if (!this.control)
      this.control=control;

    if (this.control && this.input) 
       this.input.control.setValidators(this.control.validator)

    if (control.value=="qqq")
      return {error:"Inner error:The value is 1"}

    return null
  }
```

a new [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q7qwq7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom.component.ts)

Comment: I've just looked at my code this morning and noticed that I haven't implemented blur event... And yet I am currently looking for a way to implement custom validators (required, pattern and custom must be present) on a child component and to transfer validation state and to transfer validation state to parent form

Comment: the validator can be outside the component -then you needn't make nothing or inside the component, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53793764/using-a-validation-on-a-reactive-form-control-that-is-a-component

Comment: Yes, but in my case I need them inside, only required can be conditionally set via Input decorator. Provided NG_VALIDATORS, setup validate, but it doesn't effect child control validation status... parent is ng-invalid, whereas child input is ng-valid

Comment: make a validator inside has no much sense -only if is a custom validator-. Anyway, I just discovered a more simple way to make our "input" get the errors and is copy the validators. -see my updated answer- If we has a custom validator inside, we need use the setvalidator like `setValidators([..this.control.control.validator,newValidator])`

Comment: Thanks @Eliseo. I've spend a lot to how to get to NgControl touch status. See an update of mine. Your answers really helped me!